# FormArray length does not reset by form.reset()

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on Angular forms data driven approach, I added form controls dynamically to FormArray, I used form.reset() to reset the added controls, but form.reset() doest not reset the FormArray length, I have found that this is a known issue and can be solved using this approach, https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11051 , but still I am unclear about this. Please help, Thanks

```
reviewForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.reviewForm = new FormGroup({            
      'controlArray': new FormArray([        
    ])
    });
  }

onSubmit(){     
    this.formData = new FormData(this.formService.formName, this.reviewForm.value.controlArray);    
    let formControls = JSON.stringify(this.formData); 
    // console.log(formControls);
    this.formService.createForm(formControls)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.error(error)
    );
    this.reviewForm.reset();    
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Calling reset on `FormControl`, `FormGroup` or `FormArray` will only reset the values of native html controls they are attached to. It ***won't*** delete the controls from the `DOM`.

Only way you can add controls to a `FormArray` is via your component code file (typescript) dynamically. That means you will update the `DOM` dynamically. Hence, calling `reset` on the `FormArray` will only clear the values of the dynamically added controls (set the controls to their initial state. Empty string for a input box for example). On the other hand, resetting the length of the `FromArray` requires deleting all the controls inside the `FormArray`.

So in this case you will have to set the `FormArray` control itself with an empty `FormArray`. Consider the following example which deletes all the controls of a `FormArray` by replacing it with an empty `FormArray` instance,

```
this.reviewForm.setControl('controlArray', new FormArray([]));
```

When using with a FormBuilder instance you can do it like the following,

```
this.reviewForm.setControl('controlArray', this.fb.array([])); // here, `fb` is a form builder instance
```

Comment: `fb` is just an instance of a `FormBuilder`. you can rewrite the code like, `this.reviewForm.setControl('controlArray', new FormArray([]));`. answer is updated

Comment: This break the subscriptions on that control.

Comment: then how can we reset the FormArray completely? @Twois

Comment: @sainu When we create a new FormGroup, we set the default values and in my opinion the reset function should be use them instead of clear everything and set null for everything.

Comment: As of Angular 8+ the recommended way of removing all components from a FormArray is `formArray.clear();`

Comment: I think building a new form is better than setting the form array value to null, since it's just break the subscription to the control.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to `clear` the array and add add when necessary a default array element, e.g.:

```
// All array elements are removed
(this.reviewForm.get('controlArray') as FormArray).clear();
// Other values are removed
this.reviewForm.reset();
// When necessary add an initial array element
// (this.reviewForm.get('controlArray') as FormArray).push(new FormControl('Initial Element');
```