# How to clear the FormArray values in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular

Here, I want to make the FormArray's length zero. (it is mentioned that everything works fine with this form)

```
profileForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
   this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
      nod_title: new FormControl(),
      nod_subtitle: new FormControl(null),
      nod_name: new FormControl(null),
      nod_occupation: new FormControl(null),
      nod_description: new FormControl(null),
      nod_tags: new FormArray([new FormControl('hello'), new FormControl('world')]),
    });
  }

 resetTags() {
   if (this.profileForm.value.nod_tags.length) {   // here I tried
     this.profileForm.value.nod_tags.clear();
     console.log(this.profileForm.value.nod_tags)
 }
```

```
<button type="button" (click)="resetTags()"> Reset taggs </button>
```

here, I want to empty the nod_tags value and console.log() should return an empty array.

Comment: this.profileForm.get('nod_Tags').clear(), see the docs, https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
resetTags() {
    const arr = this.profileForm.controls.nod_tags as FormArray;
    while (0 !== arr.length) {
      arr.removeAt(0);
}
```

This way worked very well. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

In the `resetTags()`, get the corresponding value of the *FormControl* that you require. Now you can call the [**reset()**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset) on it as shown below:

```
resetTags() {
   this.profileForm.controls['nod_tags'].reset();
}
```

---

From your comment, to set it to an empty array use:

```
resetTags() {
   let arr = <FormArray>this.profileForm.controls['nod_tags'];
   arr.clear();
}
```

Comment: It worked but null value is there after resetting the nod_tags property. Here I need to make the nod_tags array empty like this [ ].

Comment: Of course Sir, here it sets 2 empty strings but I need to make the array completely empty. Thanks sir.

Comment: sorry sir, console shows 'arr.clear() is not a function', even editor mark the clear() with red underline. But why! Is there any problem with any other issues. My Angular version is 7.2.15 and CLI version is 7.3.9.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? It worked fine for me.

Comment: Also, if that didn't work all you need to do is to clear the array. You already have the reference to it (i.e `arr`), now you could clear it anyway you want. If the edit didn't work for you, there are multiple other ways to clear an array in js/ts.. etc

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this as of Angular 8+ is with the [clear()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#clear) method provided with `FormArray`:

```
// Reset all tags (Angular 8+)
resetTags() {
  const nodTags = this.profileForm.get('nod_tags') as FormArray;

  if ( nodTags.length > 0 )
    nodTags.clear();
}
```

If you're using Angular 7 or below, then Mizanur's version will work. Here's a modified version of the `resetTags()` method that uses it:

```
// Reset all tags (Angular 7 and below)
resetTags() {
  const nodTags = this.profileForm.get('nod_tags') as FormArray;

  while ( nodTags.length > 0 ) {
      nodTags.removeAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```js
this.form = this._formB.group({
    blocks: this._formB.array(["a","b","c"])
});

this.form.controls['blocks'].value.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way you want to do it

```
resetTags() {
    this.nodTags.clear();
 }

 get nodTags(): FormArray {
   return this.profileForm.get('nod_tags') as FormArray;
 }
```

I also made a small [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw6vfh)

Comment: Thank you sir, but It's not working for me! it shows an error in the console (ERROR TypeError: "this.nodTags.clear is not a function").

Comment: did you add `get nodTags()` getter that I've posted?

Comment: yes sir, I've completely followed your code. Even the editor marks the clear() with red underline.

Comment: please, double check demo. Other way to do it is with the following `(<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('nod_tags')).clear();` .

Comment: when I hover over the red underlined clear() , it shows a message 'Property 'clear' does not exist on type 'FormArray'.

Comment: Sorry sir, I did not understand your second solution. Could you please make it clear for me?

Comment: You're probably using some other version of Angular. Try with `(<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('nod_tags')).controls.length = 0;`

Comment: `resetTags() {
    (<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('nod_tags')).controls.length = 0;
 }`

Comment: Where to use "(<FormArray>this.profileForm.get('nod_tags')).controls.length = 0; " sir? I've used it instead of "this.nodTags.clear();". but is not working!

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't? Both solutions work on the demo that I've provided.

Comment: Yes sir, your demo is working fine but why not it is working I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

there is more simple way to make nod_tags Empty!

```
get nod_tagsArray() {
    return this.profileForm.controls.nod_tags as FormArray;
  }

    this.nod_tagsArray.controls =[];
```